# How to install python freetype in windows 7

Tags: python, python-2.7, freetype2

I am using Windows 7 64bit, I want to install and use freetype (from https://pypi.python.org/pypi/freetype-py). I have installed gnu32 freetype6.dll, and freetype-py in my winpython 2.6. When I import freetype in my python code, the system said:

```
raise RuntimeError('Freetype library not found')
RuntimeError: Freetype library not found
```

Then, I deleted the freetype, and used pip to install freetype 1.0. When I compiled the code, the system said:

```
import freetype as FT
  File "C:\WinPython-32bit-2.7.6.4\python-2.7.6\lib\site-packages\freetype\__init__.py", line 33, in <module>
    if not FT_Library_filename:
NameError: name 'FT_Library_filename' is not defined
```

I cannot use pip to install Freetype 2 library binding, it said: could not find any downloads that satisfy the requirement Freetype.

Then, I opened `__init__.py`, and changed

```
FT_Library_filename = ctypes.util.find_library('freetype')
```

into:

```
FT_library_filename = "C:\Program Files (x86)\GnuWin32\bin\freetype.dll"
```

Still, it does not work; the system said:

```
if not FT_Library_filename:
NameError: name 'FT_Library_filename' is not defined
```

Can someone help correct this? I really need to use freetype.

Answer (score 2):

According to the installation guide, it states you need freetype 2 (copied below).  So your PIP installation with free type 1 would not have worked.

> Freetype-py 0.5.1
>
> ## Installation
>
> To be able to use freetype python, you need the freetype library
>   version 2 installed on your system.

To help clarify, when you said "*I have installed gnu32 freetype6.dll*", did you try to compile your own binaries or download the installer according to the installation guide?

http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/install.html

Comment: Yes, I download freetype for windows here: http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/freetype.htm. As for freetype 2 libaray, i cannot find it.

Comment: Now, I manage to let the system knows where to get freetype.dll, but when I import freetype in my python code, the system said:

__dll__ = ctypes.CDLL(FT_Library_filename)
  File "C:\WinPython-32bit-2.7.6.4\python-2.7.6\lib\ctypes\__init__.py", line 365, in __init__
    self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)
WindowsError: [Error 126] The specified module could not be found.

It seems that the system cannot use CDLL in ctypes, and I do not know how to fix it. It works in my win 7 home premium machine. 

Thanks.